# Adding superview method as target to UIButton of child view from superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an application in which I am having common structure of `UITableView` for all my `UIViewControllers`. 
So I have created a `UITableView` subclass containing common structure, then I have added this view to my `UIViewController`.

`UITableView` is displaying properly but I need to addTarget to `UIButton` added to Custom `UITableViewCell` from my `ViewController` and method is written in `UIViewController`.

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: are you using **storyboard** or the old system ?  if storyboard, it's possible this may help greatly http://stackoverflow.com/a/23060746/294884

Comment: @JoeBlow: Yes I am using Storyboard

Comment: @JoeBlow I tried to do it by using container view controller but this is not working as per my requirement as on `UIButton` click my table height is changing

Comment: @ShitalTiwari : Kindly go for `NSNotificationCenter` as described in my answer. There is a sample code link that explains the usage of `NSNotificationCenter` in a custom sub-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work on your Program design to get this problem sorted. However you have come far enough to go back & change your design. So for you the better option is the `NSNotificationCenter`.

For your case, do this:

1. In your viewController where your method is written, lets say method name is `myX-Method:` (which performs the button's target functionality), then in the `viewDidLoad` of this controller just add this line.

   ```
   -(void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myX-Method:) name:@"NOTIFY_CUSTOM_BUTTON" object:nil];
   }
   ```
2. Now, in your `UITableViewCell` class, set a local method as buttons target as normally we do, lets say , `myLocalMethod:`
3. Now in this local method, post the notification message like this. For example I am just passing the current cell's button text as message to notification.

   ```
   -(void) myLocalMethod:(UIButton *)button{
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTIFY_CUSTOM_BUTTON" object: button.title];
   }
   ```

This way you need not have to be dependent on delegate or so. Use notification object to collect your values in `myX-Method:` like this :

```
-(void)myX-Method:(NSNotification *)dict {
    NSString *buttonTitle = [dict valueForKey:@"object"];
    NSLog(@"Button Clicked : %@", buttonTitle);
}
```

Hope this simple solution will solve your purpose.

Refer [here](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/collection.zip) for a sample code. However in example code project, kindly search `NSNotificationCenter`

Answer (score 0):

you can set the cell delegate as the view controller at tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

then when a button is pressed inside the cell you can trigger the delegate method inside the buttonPressed: method in the cell.

so the **cell** calls **cell.delegate** which is the viewController

in CellView.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;
```

in CellView.m

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate cellButttonPressed:sender];
}
```

in MyTableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CellView *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}

- (void)cellButttonPressed:(id)sender {
//button action code here
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Delegate Methods For Example

Make SubClass of UITableViewCell

Declare Delegate Methods

```
  @protocol  CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)btnClikced;

@end
```

// InterFace

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic,retain) id<CustomCellDelegate> delegate;
```

//implementation

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.accessoryView=btn;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)btnTapped{
    [self.delegate btnClikced];
}
```

in your ViewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.delegate = self;
return cell;
```

}

```
- (void)btnClikced{
//button action code here
}
```